# UICollectionView Cell not changing upon selecting

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In my project, I have a UICollectionView. In the UICollectionView, I have a custom cell.

I am able to print the cell value when it is selected within "didSelectItemAt", however, if I try to edit the cell in any way within this method, it does not change.

I'm sure I'm missing something, any help would be appreciated!

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return statValues.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "customCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! customCollectionViewCell

    cell.statLabel.text = statHeaders[indexPath.row]
    cell.statLabel.textColor = UIColor(red:0.31, green:0.31, blue:0.31, alpha:1.0)

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "customCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! customCollectionViewCell

    print(cell.statLabel.text)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    collectionView.reloadData()

}
```

When user selects a cell, the code is correctly printing the value of the indexPath, however the backgroundColor does not change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess would be that you are creating a new instance of cell instead of using the one in the collectionView

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Change this line
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath)

    print(cell.statLabel.text)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    collectionView.reloadData()

}
```

Also, you should probably keep an external data model for your source of truth. If you have enough collectionViews that requires scrolling, when you scroll offscreen, your cells will be reused in a random order causing cells that you did not click to be yellow.

Create a seperate array such as

```
var selectedStatHeaders: Set<Int>()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "customCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! customCollectionViewCell

    cell.statLabel.text = statHeaders[indexPath.row]
    cell.statLabel.textColor = UIColor(red:0.31, green:0.31, blue:0.31, alpha:1.0)
    // Reset/configure cell each reload
    if selectedStatHeaders.contains(indexPath.row) { // Can also make this into a ternary
      cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    } else {
      cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whit
    }
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedStatHeaders.insert(indexPath.row)
    collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPath(indexPath: indexpath)
}
```

Comment: This should work, also no need to call reloadData, should use reloadItems instead.

Comment: ^ Edited for better answer

Comment: Also, just a suggestion, whenever using tableviews/collectionview whose cells are reused, you should cache you colors instead of calling UIColor() in cellforRow/Item as this is called multiple times and might lead to memory issues.

Comment: This solution worked! I was indeed creating a new instance of cell instead of using the one in the collectionView, knew I was missing something, thank you @Mocha

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Doesn't make sense if the code is able to print but the background doesn't change color. Do you mean changing back from yellow to white? Anyway, just a hunch but I suspect it's because you are calling `collectionView.reloadData()` after your set the backgroundColor change.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618078-reloaddata

> This causes the collection view to discard any currently visible
>   items (including placeholders) and recreate items based on the current
>   state of the data source object.